# How to efficiently formalize an optimization problem for python

Tags: python, optimization, solver

I have an optimization problem that I could set up as either a rather complex univariate problem with a non-linear optimization function, or as a multivariate problem with linear optimization function.

Is it possible to somewhat generalize whether from a programming perspective, one is more efficient than the other? I.e. even without going into the details of the functions and constraints, are solvers more efficient with functionally complex univariate problems over simple multivariate problems or vice versa?

I tried to google the problem but the results I read were all looking at examples that didn't even require numerical solving. (e.g. [this](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/optimization-in-python))

Once I figured out the best approach I'll implement it in python.

Comment: Implementing two solution methods is a good quality assurance thing. If they both arrive at the same solution you can have more confidence in the correctness of the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ErwinKalvelagen.
I guess with some time I will implement both then (Y)